# Loading CSV into d3 v5?

Tags: d3.js

I'm using Mike Bostock's example found here: (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051).

Nothing shows up on my local page, and I keep receiving an error saying

```
Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Other/WebDev/test/data.csv. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
jo @ d3.v5.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ d3.v5.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ groupedBar.html:38
```

I also get one saying

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at jo (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at Object.csv (d3.v5.min.js:2)
    at groupedBar.html:38
jo @ d3.v5.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ d3.v5.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ groupedBar.html:38
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ d3.v5.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ groupedBar.html:38
```

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>

.axis .domain {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);






d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text("Population");

  var legend = g.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(keys.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 19)
      .attr("width", 19)
      .attr("height", 19)
      .attr("fill", z);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
});

</script>
```

Can anyone help me understand what I need to change? I'm able to download the CSV from the web page, so it looks like its uploading properly.

Comment: There are two problems in your code: 1) You are not using the v5 API correctly. See [*"How to load data from a CSV file in D3 v5"*](/q/49599691) 2) You cannot load local files like you do. See [*"Importing local json file using d3.json does not work"*](/q/17214293) or [*"“Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.” error when loading a local file"*](/q/10752055).